# require spine mobile using Sprockets in rails 3.1.0

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, mobile, sprockets, spine.js

I would like to use the mobile library for spine in Rails 3.1.0.
I tried adding the following to my index.js.coffee:

```
#= require spine.mobile
```

and

```
#= require spine/mobile
```

But that both results in an error: couldn't find file

When using hem you can specify the dependencies in the slug.json file and run

```
npm install .
```

How do I install dependencies using Rails/Sprockets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using [spine.mobile-rails](https://github.com/hiddenbek/spine.mobile-rails)?

Just add the following to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'spine.mobile-rails', :git => 'https://github.com/goyox86/spine.mobile-rails.git'
```

And `require 'spine.mobile-rails'` in your `application.js`.

Note that spine.js has also excellent integration with rails, via the spine-rails gem, with great scaffolding to get you started. Not sure if this is relevant for the mobile part.

Comment: When I add the gem to my `Gemfile` and run `bundle install` I get this error: `Could not find gem 'spine.mobile-rails (>= 0, runtime)' in any of the gem sources`.

Comment: Ah indeed: apparently the gem was never pushed to rubygems.org. You can use a gem from github, I instantly propose to use the version from goyox86, which includes the correct styling templates as well. HTH.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot! I didn't had to require anything in the **application.js** I just added `#= require spine/touch` to **index.js.coffee**.